# How do I get a variable into a $(shell) command in a makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

```
❯ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
❯ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)
```

How can I pass a variable from inside a for loop to $(shell)? I can access the var outside of $(shell) but I can't figure out how to pass it in:

```
A_LIST:= one two

.PHONY: loop
loop:
    @for iii in $(A_LIST) ; do \
        echo inside recipe loop with sh command: $$iii ; \
        export SAVED_OUTPUT=$(shell echo $$iii) ; \
        echo $$SAVED_OUTPUT ; \
    done
```

This is the output I get:

```
inside recipe loop with sh command: one
<blank line here>
inside recipe loop with sh command: two
<blank line here>
```

The last line in the loop `echo $$SAVED_OUTPUT` should output `one` and `two` because it is echoing the var and storing it in another var. But it is a blank line. I suspect it's because it's looking for an env var `$iii` but that doesn't exist- so how to I pass the value of `iii` into the shell?

Here is a bad way of doing this I don't like. I don't want to have to write a local file just to access a variable like this:

```
.PHONY: loop
loop:
    @for iii in $(A_LIST) ; do \
        echo inside recipe loop with sh command: $$iii ; \
        echo $$iii > scratch ; \
        export SAVED_OUTPUT=$(shell echo $$(cat scratch)) ; \
        echo $$SAVED_OUTPUT ; \
    done
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description).

Comment: added desired output to it

Comment: There's no need to use the make `$(shell)` function here in something that's already being executed by a shell...

Comment: `export` exports variables to child processes. There's no way to set variables in a parent process.

Comment: i need to store the output of the shell command to use for another shell command and chain them together

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` loop is already being executed by a shell - in this case, there's no reason to bring `$(shell ...)` into it too. Just use normal `$()` shell command substitution syntax (Doubling up the `$` to make make happy, like with the variable names):

```
A_LIST:= one two

.PHONY: loop
loop:
    @for iii in $(A_LIST) ; do \
        echo "inside recipe loop with sh command: $$iii" ; \
        SAVED_OUTPUT="$$(somecommand "$$iii")" ; \
        echo "$$SAVED_OUTPUT" ; \
    done
```

Comment: I need to use the value of iii for a shell command and store the output of that shell command in SAVED_OUTPUT

Comment: @red888 So use normal shell notation (With escaping `$` to prevent evaluation by make): `SAVED_OUTPUT="$$(somecommand "$$iii")"`

Comment: wow that actually works. I was going to remove my question because its such an ugly thing to do in the first place now that i look at it, but good to know its possible. Can you add that to your answer?

Answer (score -1):

An easy and clean way is to use the "pass parameters" shell feature:
VAR=value ./myscript.sh

```
    SRC := ./src
    OBJ := ./obj
    
    .PHONY  mytest
mytest:
       $(shell SOURCE_DIR=$(SRC) OBJECT_DIR=$(OBJ) ./mytestscript.sh)
```

And inside ./mytestscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Source directory is "$(SOURCE_DIR)", and Object directory is "$(OBJECT_DIR)"
```

Output:

Source directory is ./src, and Object directory is ./obj

Comment: That's crazy. Don't do this. The same thing works fine without the `$(shell ...)` wrapper around it; but with it, you are telling `make` to try to run the output from the `$(shell ...)` invocation as the actual recipe.